# requisição de Ajax com PHP não reconhece scripts

Tags: php, ajax, script

Estou criando um código, onde envio um formulário com ajax e retorno o resultado obtido em um arquivo PHP(comment.php), porém este arquivo ignora os scripts linkados na página onde o formulário está contido (pergunta.php):

**Código ajax (pergunta.php):**

```
    jQuery(document).ready(function(){
    jQuery('.formcomment').submit(function(){

    var dados = jQuery( this ).serialize();

       jQuery.ajax({
         type: "POST",
         url: "comment.php",
         data: dados,
         success: function(response){

          var editorContent = tinyMCE.get('camporesposta').getContent();
          if (editorContent == "" || editorContent == null){
           $("#aviso").html("<div class='alert alert-warning alert-dismissible' role='alert'><button type='button' class='close' data-dismiss='alert' aria-label='Close'><span aria-hidden='true'>&times;</span></button><strong><i class='fa fa-meh-o'></i> Preencha o campo de resposta!</strong></div> ");
          } else{
            $("#aviso").html("<div class='alert alert-warning alert-dismissible' role='alert'><button type='button' class='close' data-dismiss='alert' aria-label='Close'><span aria-hidden='true'>&times;</span></button><strong><i class='fa fa-meh-o'></i> Resposta inserida com sucesso!</strong></div> ");
             document.getElementById("ajaxrespostas").innerHTML=response;
            }



         }
        });
        return false;
      });
    });
```

**Neste arquivo linkei os scripts abaixo:**

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script  type="text/javascript"  src="node_modules/bootstrap/js/tinymce/tinymce.min.js"></script>
<script src='https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/mathjax/2.7.5/MathJax.js?config=TeX-MML-AM_CHTML' async></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="node_modules/bootstrap/js/tinymce/plugins/tiny_mce_wiris/tests/js/google_analytics.js"></script>
```

No entanto, ao retornar a página (comment.php) na variável "response" definida no código ajax, ele simplesmente deixa de reconhecer os script acima:

**comment.php:**

```
<?php 
    require_once 'db.php';
    include 'functions.php';
?>

<?php

    // Variável enviada do formulário 
    $resposta= $_POST['resposta'];
    $idpergunta= $_POST['idPergunta'];

    if ($resposta == null){
        echo "falha";
        die();

    } else{


    $sql = "INSERT INTO respostas (texto, idUsuario, datapostagem, idPergunta) VALUES ('$resposta', '$iduser', current_date, '$idpergunta')";
    $insert = $mysqli->query($sql);

    include("comentarios.php");
}
```

**resultado (página pergunta.php, inicialmente com os scripts sendo reconhecidos):**
[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

**resultado após ser feita a requisição do ajax (página pergunta.php com a página comment.php retornada na variável response, scripts não reconhecidos)**
[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

como vocês podem ver, os scripts responsáveis pelo editor de texto e pelas fórmulas matemáticas não são carregados.

Comment: Não tenho certeza se entendi, mas os javascripts não etão sendo carregados? Se for isso tente adicionar a propriedade `async` a todas tags `<script>`

Comment: Sim, os scripts não são reconhecidos. Tentei, mas sem sucesso :(

Comment: Então, simular esse código aqui é difícil, mas você já tentou remover o callback do success para verificar se é o AJAX em sí, ou sua função que está quebrando a página?
Uma coisa que eu estou sentindo falta é o preventDefault do submit. Você não deveria receber um evento como parâmetro no ('.formcomment').submit, e então chamar o método preventDefault para impedir que sua página recarregue ao fazer um submit?

Comment: pode me exemplificar como ficaria isso? Sou iniciante no assunto.